# Calculating the difference between two fields within a table in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a model which stores the opening and closing balances of a petrol station. I have an additional third column which is basically the difference between the opening and reading values.

```
class DailySales(models.Model):
    PUMP_NAMES = (
    ...
    )
    Pump_name = models.CharField(max_length = 5, choices = PUMP_NAMES)
    Opening_reading = models.IntegerField()
    Closing_reading = models.IntegerField()
    Gross_sales = models.IntegerField(null = True)
    Date = models.DateField(auto_now_add= True)

    def Calc_gross(self):
        self.Gross_sales = self.Opening_reading - self.Closing_reading
        super(DailySales,self).save()
```

the Calc_gross method works when i'm saving only one instance at a time.
But i want to add multiple opening and closing values to the model at once for which i'm using formsets.

```
SalesForm = modelformset_factory(DailySales, extra = 7, exclude=('Date','Gross_sales'))
```

This is where the logic falters. Django isnt able to calculate the gross values for each row.

```
Exception Value:    

'list' object has no attribute 'Calc_gross'
```

I was thinking since its a list , I could iterate over each and invoke the Calc_gross method. What will be the name of the list?

Is there a better way to do this? Would it be logical to use Prefixes (how would u assign a prefix to each form?)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i could just loop over the formset.

if request.method == 'POST':
        sale_Form = SalesForm(data = request.POST)

```
    for Form in sale_Form:

        if Form.is_valid():

            gross = Form.save()


            gross.Calc_gross()
            gross.save()
        else:
            print(sale_Form.errors)
```